# Ошибка CS0234 Тип "Forms" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Windows" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку)

Tags: c#, uwp, messagebox

В общем, сама идея в чем- для практики хочу сделать игру 15(пятнашки) на с#.
На видео([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSgq6QtcoDc&t=1s)) игра пишется под Windows Forms, но я ее потихоньку адаптирую к UWP. Столкнулся с этой проблемой дальше пока пройти не могу, она конечно не нужна для приложения, но почему оно не работает?!?

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace _15Game
{

   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
       }


       private void Button0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Button btn = (Button)sender;
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
       }
   }
}
```

"System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test")" - это подчеркивается красным и пишет что не найден тип или пространство имен Forms ...

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` находится в другой сборке, которая по умолчанию в WPF проекты не подключается. А вообще в WPF есть свой MessageBox, попробуйте убрать `System.Windows.Forms.` вовсе. И почему у вас в WPF приложении подключены пространства имен из UWP? Что-то вы недоговариваете

Comment: Возможно я что то напутал

Comment: Хм, я делаю приложение под Windows 10 , и я так понимаю это уже не WPF  а UWP ...
Но даже если так- почему оно не работает?? И да, я пробовал удалять System.Windows.Forms - ошибка все равно есть, но немного другая -
"Имя MSGBox не существует в текущем контексте"
Нужно как то отдельно вызывать MSGBox?

Comment: В UWP таких окон нет, смотрите диалоги: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22909631/6766879) [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/)

Comment: Дельный совет - поставьте аддон Метро из нугета, и пользуйтесь контролами через него, там все просто получиться.. нежели такой зоопарк из технологий устраивать :)

Comment: UWP, WPF и WinForms - это разные технологии. Определитесь для начала, с чем хотите работать.

Comment: Видео на WinForms, хочу работать на UWP